# How to integrate my own scraper in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have just created a Rails app with a model **app/models/post.rb** and have written a scraper **scrapers/base_scraper.rb** (class **BaseScraper**) that collect data from the target site to the hash variable **data**. Now I want to insert values of data into the **Post** model. How to do it properly in Rails? I have heard smth about Rake but have no idea how to utilize it properly. Help me please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `data` stores just one post and that each of the key stored in the `data`hash are valid `Post` fields (column_name), you can do simply this:

```
Post.create(data)
```

If you want to launch the whole process from console, you can create a rake task under `lib/tasks` directory of your process with the following:

```
# scraper.rake
namespace :scraper do
  desc "Run scraper"
  task :run => :environment do
    data = BaseScraper.your_collect_data_class_method
    Post.create(data) if data
  end
end

task :default => 'scraper:run'
```

And then run it from console as a rake task with `rake scraper`

Of course I also assume that `scrapers` dir is in your Rails load path.
If not, add it to your `application.rb`file.

```
# application.rb
...
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/scrapers/"]
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: don't I need to import Post class to scrapers/base_scraper.rb somehow?

Comment: There is a problem with your code: you should change `task :run` to `task :run => :environment` to auto load rails models, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that class BaseScraper from the scrapers/ folder will be available in this file? Just to be sure.

Comment: Of course I also assume that scrapers dir is included in the load path of your Rails app...

Comment: If not, add it to your `application.rb`file.


    module YourApp
      class Application < Rails::Application
        ...
        config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/scrapers/"]
        ...
      end
    end